# Update counter using php and mysql in a session

Tags: php, html, sql, session, counter

***Problem:*** I want to connect two tables files and counter according to the paper_id column from files table connecting with the visitors column from counter table.

There are two pages; publicationView.php and profile.php. 
When a reader clicks publicationView.php, php code should count the view of the page according to the publication id and only update using session. 
When a user visits his profile.php, then he can see his publications in a table with the publications' views relatively.

There are two tables; files where all the publications are and counter where the counter are. I am trying to update using the URI of the publication and the URI is saved in counter table.

***Implementation:***

The publicationView.php includes

```
$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

 $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS counter (
 id int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 webpage varchar(90) NOT NULL,
 visitors int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1"; 

mysql_query($sql);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM counter WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter (id, webpage, visitors)
 VALUES ('','$webpage','1')");

 }else{

 if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage'] = 0;
  mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+'1' WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}
```

The profile.php includes

The code to echo our the visitors column from counter table.

Comment: visitors+'1' = > visitors+1

Answer (score 0):

Change `'1'` to simply `1` in,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage'] = 0;
  mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+'1' WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}
```

Change it to

```
 if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage'] = 0;
  mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Optimus. It does upgrade the hits. However in the profile.php, I want to echo out the views from the counter table respectively to the list of publications in files table. Basically, I want to link files_id from files table with the visitors column from the counter table.

Comment: @SandeshMgr so what problem are you facing in doing that?

Comment: the codes increment the counter views. Now I wanted to join two different tables.

Comment: @SandeshMgr And what have you tried for that? And how does the webpage relate with your files table?